# Can't click on the website using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I thought I understood the concept but I guess I don't ..

I would like to click on a button from a list of tabs on a HTML page

```
<div id="subTabs2">
<div id="subTabs">
            
<ul>

<li>
<a class="currentTab" id="sub_tab_timeclock_today" href="?p=timeclock:today">Today</a>
</li>

<li>
<a id="sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet" href="?p=timeclock:my_timesheet">My timesheet</a>
</li>

#list continues ....
```

I would like to click on the tab "sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet" so in my code I did

```
# some code

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)

driver.get(url)


username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_handle")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")

username.send_keys("myUser")
password.send_keys("myPass")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("button1").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet").click()
```

I did pass the login page but then I don't understand why my code doesn't work for clicking on the tab "My timesheet" which has the ID "sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet".

The error message is :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the element with id = `sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet` not visible until your click the element with class name `button1`?

Comment: The way it works is that , indeed I first go to login page with only username / password fields. Once the code fill out both fields and then click on the "Login" button ( button1 ), then It goes to another webpage including those tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be encountering a timing issue. Try implementing a wait in between `driver.find_element_by_class_name("button1").click()` and `driver.find_element_by_id("sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet").click()`.

To do so, you'll need to do something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sub_tab_timeclock_my_timesheet"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Not too sure about the Python code as I'm a .NET dev, but check this article for syntax specifics:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Good call, I'm gonna check that first and validate your answer if it works. thanks!

Comment: You point me to the right direction thank you. By using "driver.implicitly_wait(10)" between my login form submit and then cliking on the tab , it worked properly ! thanks again!

Comment: You should also do a wait for the user_handle after you get the url due to page loading.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped you out! Best of luck!